# android beacon library get state for region

Tags: android, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon, beacon

BootstrapNotifier (i.e. MonitorNotifier) have callback for entering / exiting region but how to get the region state at app startup (how can app realize to be already IN a region)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/) version 2.8.1, the only way to do this is via accessing some internal library classes like this:

`if (MonitoringStatus.getInstanceForApplication(this).stateOf(region) != null && MonitoringStatus.getInstanceForApplication(this).stateOf(region).isInside()) {
            // Do something 
        }`

I would recommend against using this in production code, as this internal API is subject to change.  In the **next version** of the library will have a way to get this information on the BeaconManager as so:

```
beaconManager.requestStateForRegion(region);
```

The above method will cause a callback to be made on the MonitorNotifier or BootstrapNotifier: `didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region);`

Comment: Many thanks, really. It works! Even without replacing the "do something" section the didDetermineStateForRegion callback is called: very good. It's ok for tests and I'll wait for next release of library before going in production ;-)